# How do I add a cooldown for a command on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to make a cooldown for a function on discord.py. I made it in a test.py file and it works, but in my main file it doesnt.
How do you think I could go about fixing this issue? I have looked through many videos and Im not sure why this doesn't work. The "rasp farm" function works and the cool down does too, but I want a message to appear when there is a cool down, with this code I get the error

```
# python main.py

import os
import discord
import wikipedia
from discord.utils import get
import time
import random
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import json
from discord.ext.commands import cooldown, BucketType
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands


os.chdir(r"C:\Users\laksh\PycharmProjects\Raspberry")
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='rasp ')


# Start up
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')



@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s raspberries", color=discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name= "Wallet",value=wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name="Bank", value=bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)


@commands.cooldown(1, 3, commands.BucketType.user)
@bot.command()
async def farm(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    earnings = random.randrange(201)

    await ctx.send(f"You picked {earnings} raspberries!! (Raspberries take 1 minute to grow again!)")

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        users = json.dump(users,f)
@farm.error
async def farm_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, farm.CommandOnCooldown):
        em = discord.Embed(title=f"You are in cooldown",description=f"Try again in {error.retry_after:.2f}s.", color=discord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.send(embed=em)

async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0
    with open("mainbank.json","w") as a:
        users = json.dump(users,a)
    return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as a:
        users = json.load(a)
    return users



@bot.command()
async def commands(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="My commands:", description="My prefix is 'rasp' for example a command is 'rasp farm'.",
                          color=0xff4d4d)
    embed.add_field(name="'rasp farm'", value="Farms your ripened raspberries!                ", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name=" 'rasp balance'", value="Checks how many raspberries your wallet and bank holds!",
                    inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="'rasp shop'", value="Buy items to multiply your raspberry earnings :yum:", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: The error I get is discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'CommandOnCooldown'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to access the error class from your command, which doesn't have one. You have to access `discord.ext.commands.CommandOnCooldown` instead of `farm.CommandOnCooldown`

Comment: Thank you so much, this works well! Have a great day, Mr.Chuaat!